# insertion sort for an object-array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

For instance, I have the following classes:

```
public class FooService {

    private String name;
    private int quantity;

    public FooService(String name, int quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    // getters + setters
}
```

and

```
public class FooStorage {

    private FooService [] services = new FooService[10];

    public void add(FooService fooService) {

    }
}
```

**I want to sort the services array in an alphabetical order according to each element's name parameter.**

I know I can use a comparator in this case but it is very expensive when importing large amount of data. Can anyone help me with the insertion sort here?

EDIT: I am not allowed to use Collections. Also, do not mind about the fixed size of the array. I am allocating initially 5000 slots and then multiplying by 2 if the 5000th slot is reached in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really keen on insertion sort try this..

```
public void sort(){
    for(int i=2;i<services.length;i++){
        int j=i-1;
        FooService key=services[i];
        while((j>-1)&& ((services[j].getName().compareTo(key.getName()))>0)){
            services[j+1]=services[j];
            j--;
        }
        services[j+1]=key;
    }
}
```

**P.S.** You ain't using collections... `compareTo()` is just helping you on string comparisons, to implement your own string comparisons will be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: btw, why did you assign i as 2 in the first for loop? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Make `FooService` implement `Comparable`. Make the `compareTo` method compare by alphabetic order. 
And then use `Arrays.sort(services);` it will sort your array.

Read more here: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

Answer (score 2):

If you are periodically adding lots of new items into your array then the `Arrays.sort()` approach described by @Jakkra is a sound approach.

If you're frequently only adding a few items each time then this approach is a bit heavy-weight, you might want to consider a `TreeSet` (also requires implementing `Comparable`).

EDIT: Just seen your update saying you cannot use collections (!), so the second option is no good to you but I'll leave it here for posterity.